# Spotlight and command-B shortcut quirk

Tags: spotlight

When I open Spotlight and type something in, I can search that query using command-B shortcut (i.e. when I type something into Spotlight and press command-B, my search query is sent to the default search engine of the Safari). There is a small quirk however. If Safari app is opened, Spotlight window stays on and I have to close it down manually (two escape keys). However, if Safari app is completely closed, Spotlight window closes automatically.

Here's two screenshots to show visually what I mean:

Spotlight -> type "example" in -> press command-B (prior to doing this, Safari was completely closed i.e. it was quit).

[image]

Spotlight -> type "example" in -> press command-B
(prior to doing this, Safari was opened)

[image]

My question is the following - is this the standard behaviour or I have bug/misconfiguration on my Mac? My OS is 10.12.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running 10.12.6, too, and it works the same way for me.

If I follow the exact same steps as you described, I get the same results that you get.  I'm assuming this is normal behavior.

Comment: Same here as well. Didn't know about the command+B at all, so this is a great addition to the workflow! :)

Comment: This answers my question but wanted to add a small nuance that clarifies this behaviour: if the focus is not on Safari.app, the Spotlight window will automatically hide. If the focus is on Safari.app, the Spotlight window will remain open despite opening a new tab. Practically speaking, I found so far only one real world example of this - if you close every tab and every window of Safari but the focus will remain on the app (top bar will read "Safari"), Spotlight window will not automatically hide.